# Magento 2: MiniCart issues

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, mini-cart

I found a bug in the mini-cart:

You add products to your cart - then in the mini-cart you click "Proceed to Checkout" - then immediately click on "View and Edit Cart".

The result is - **a empty cart**.

I've tested the issue with *v2.2.3* till *v2.2.6* - result is every time the same.

Uploaded a video to dropbox so that you can see the behavior: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/945yyoezh48h386/WhatsApp%20Video%202018-10-19%20at%2012.18.21.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Is it doing the same thing when  double clicking on "Proceed to Checkout"?

Comment: Yes, it's the sam behavior

Comment: Try to apply the commit from my answer ;) Should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by disabling the buttons once they were clicked.

I had an issue when double/triple clicking on "Proceed to checkout" emptied the cart.

I applied this commit and it fixed the problem: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9a799f130a0a8b64028de6258e7cf1378bc9bc8f/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/proceed-to-checkout.js

Would recommend doing the same one the "View and Edit Cart" button.

Comment: thanks for the hint. tried this solution - it doesn't work. the proceed-to-checkout.js disabled the button in the cart - not in minicart.

Comment: How about applying the same logic to the rest of the buttons?

Comment: How can i send my EventObserver log message by whatsapp message? @Greg